# Реализация соединения двух смартфонов посредством мобильной сети

Tags: java, android, сокет

Нашёл массу примеров реализации андроид - ПК, но очень мало информации о соединении андроид - андроид. Куда копать, что почитать (конкретно, ибо в учебниках как правило рассматриваются варианты андроид <-> localhost на ПК). Спасибо.

Comment: Промежуточный прокси сервер нужен.

Comment: Что же напрямую вообще никак (без посредника)?

Comment: Откуда вы ip возьмёте вообще, если напрямую делать? Только в локальной wi-fi сети можно обойтись без сервера.

Comment: Ну да. Логично.

Comment: Может можно реализовать сервер+клиент в одном приложении? Кто создал допустим игру тот и сервер, а второй подключается. Не?

Comment: Куда подключается? ip ваш он как узнает?

Comment: Да. Всё сходится на использование некоего посредника.

Comment: воспользуйтесь облочный сервисом. firebase например

Comment: Есть бесплатный хостинг. Нужно будет узнать на счёт сервера у них.